# Problem with installing pc game Rome Total War on Ubuntu via Wine

Tags: wine, games

Need your help. Sorry for my explanation, I'm only beginner using Ubuntu.

I have problem installing "Rome Total war" via `Wine` on my computer.

I've installed the following on my `Wine`:

```
corefonts vcrun 2005 vcrun 2008 vcrun 2010 vcrun 6 vcrun 6sp d3dx9 dotnet 20 vb5run vb6run vcrun 2003 dotnet 30 ---problem with installation occured(soft is not supported on 64 machines d3xof devenum dinput8 direckmusik direcktplay directx9 dxdiagn d3dx11_43 mfc40 wsh56js, wsh56vb, wsh57 gdiplus physx gfw wmp10 --- problem with installation occured(soft is not supported on 64 machines dirac, dmsynth, mfc42, msasn1, msxml6, quartz, xact, xact_jun2010, xinput, glut, gecko120, d3dcompiler, d3dx10, d3dxof
```

Config's of my computer:

- memory: 3,7 Gb.
- processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz × 2
- Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
- OS: Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit
- Wine version: 1.7.38

Game installation finished with success, but when opened the icon the game started with divided in many squares on the screen, so i suppose, that it is problem with graphics (video), because audio works ok and "New Campaign" starts good as well.